# Kotlin - Sort List by using formatted date string (functional)

Tags: sorting, date, kotlin

I'm trying to create a Kotlin REST API, which retrieves values from a PostgreSQL database. Now the values in these results are f.e. `"14-10-2016 | 15:48"` and `"01-08-2015 | 09:29"` So the syntax basically is `dd-MM-yyyy | hh:mm`

Now what I'm trying to do is create a function that will order them by date placed. (Assume these strings are in an array)

```
var list = listOf("14-10-2016 | 15:48",
                  "01-08-2015 | 09:29",
                  "15-11-2016 | 19:43")
```

What would be the cleanest (and most functional) way of sorting these? (so f.e. is there a way where I don't have to take substrings of the day, month, etc. cast them to an `Int`, compare them in a nested loop and write the results to a different array? (that's the only way I could think of).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

More than one approach can be used. It depends on how you process after you get the sorted result.

Points to note:

- `java.time.LocalDateTime` has already implemented
  `java.lang.Comparable<T>` Interface. We can use the kotlin stdlib `List.sortBy` to sort the `List<LocalDateTime>` directly.

Ref:

```
// https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html
fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> Iterable<T>.sortedBy(
    selector: (T) -> R?
): List<T>
```

The easiest way is to transform the `String -> java.time.LocalDateTime` and use the `List.sortBy` directly.

The whole implementation could be like this:

```
 import java.time.LocalDateTime
 import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

 ...


// Create a convert function, String -> LocalDateTime
val dateTimeStrToLocalDateTime: (String) -> LocalDateTime = {
    LocalDateTime.parse(it, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy | HH:mm"))
}

val list = listOf("14-10-2016 | 15:48",
        "01-08-2015 | 09:29",
        "15-11-2016 | 19:43")

// You will get List<LocalDateTime> sorted in ascending order
list.map(dateTimeStrToLocalDateTime).sorted()

// You will get List<LocalDateTime> sorted in descending order
list.map(dateTimeStrToLocalDateTime).sortedDescending()

// You will get List<String> which is sorted in ascending order
list.sortedBy(dateTimeStrToLocalDateTime)

// You will get List<String> which is sorted in descending order
list.sortedByDescending(dateTimeStrToLocalDateTime)
```

If you want to use `org.joda.time.DateTime`, you can just make a tiny change on the convert function.

A friendly reminder, always pick `val` as your first choice in Kotlin :).

Comment: @elect Immutable objects are always easier to trace and can be used in mutli-threaded environment without any worries. Most of the time you won't need `var` in Kotlin if you are familiar with functional approach. But `var` is more memory efficient, use it wisely to take the only benefit.

Comment: Call requires API level 26 though. Any backward compatible solutions?

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative to the excellent Saravana answer (for minimalist and compact freaks like me..) is:

```
val cmp = compareBy<String> { LocalDateTime.parse(it, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy | HH:mm")) }

list.sortedWith(cmp).forEach(::println)

01-08-2015 | 09:29
14-10-2016 | 15:48
15-11-2016 | 19:43
```

Ps: `it` is the default variable for single inputs

Comment: instead of using `map` to print, maybe use `list.sortedWith(cmp).forEach(::println)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DateTimeFormatter` to parse and then compare with `LocalDateTime`

```
    List<String> dates = Arrays.asList("14-10-2016 | 15:48", "01-08-2015 | 09:29", "15-11-2016 | 19:43");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy | HH:mm");
    List<LocalDateTime> dateTimes = dates.stream().map(date -> LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter)).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(dateTimes);
```

Output

```
[2015-08-01T09:29, 2016-10-14T15:48, 2016-11-15T19:43]
```

**Update**

You could simply convert to `LocalDateTime` in `Comparator` alone

```
List<String> sortedDates = dates.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(date -> LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

output

```
[01-08-2015 | 09:29, 14-10-2016 | 15:48, 15-11-2016 | 19:43]
```

Comment: Not sure Kotlin is compatible with Java 8, but anyway, I guess the OP was looking for a solution written in Kotlin.

Comment: @Egor sorry, I know Java only but the logic would be similar to the answer I posted

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom object dates list sorted as below.

```
println("--- ASC ---")  
dates.sortBy { it.year }
println("--- DESC ---")
dates.sortByDescending { it.year }
```

You can use sortByDescending {it.field} for descending order.